# Cannot add data in a lookup table in mysql

Tags: mysql, lookup-tables

Hey I want to add data to a lookup table and something goes wrong.

I have two tables:
The first table `books` `[id_book(PK), title, author, genre, publication_yr, publ_city]` contains 5 entries in total.
The second table `genres` `[id_genre (PK), genre]` contains 4 entries in total.

The lookup table `books_genres` `[id_books_genres (PK), id_books(Fk), id_genres(Fk)]`.

I tried to derive data from the two above tables and add them to the lookup table. I used the query

```
    INSERT INTO books_genres (id_book, id_genre)
    SELECT id_book, id_genre FROM books JOIN genres
    on books.id_book = genres.id_genre;
```

And I hoped to see 5 entries (one for each book), 3 `distinct` `id_genre` and 2 identical since two of the books shares the same genre.

However I take back only 4 entries (instead of 5). Also the results are not proper in a way that the relation is not correct. Now in the lookup table a fiction book is tag as religion.

How does the matching taking place? How the `id_book` **1** will be connected with the `id_genre` **2** (and not with the `id_genre` **3**)? I mean how does the maching of a book with its proper genre is taking place? Do I have to take this info from another table?

Comment: Yes that's true. I have 4 distinct id_genre related to 5 id_book. So two id_book share the same id_genre. But these two books have different title and authors so I counted as different entries.

Comment: I'm really new on this. And I cannot understand how the connection is made. I put the query and how is it possible a very specifi id_book that has to be connected to a very specific id_genre, indeed will be connected properly in the lookup table. What are fields/commands that do the action? In my case I am sure I miss something and there is a mixed up with the books and genres. They are only 5 entries so I can see that

Answer (score 0):

You joinning the table according to their ids. the genre table has 4 row ids 1,2,3 and 4. And the table book has 5 row therefore has ids 1,2,3,4 and 5. The join by id returns a new joined-table for each book that fulfill: books.id_book = genres.id_genre; But the book with id=5 has no pair therefore joined row is not created

Comment: I see. How about the other thing I don't get. I miss the logic behind the action I guess.. How Can I be sure that the above query will link the proper id_book with the proper id_genre? Should I make another connection I haven't done yet? The 'book' table and the 'genre' table are stand alone tables and their entries as well, so how the proper links will be made? (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: That is the porpose of the lookup table... for example if you want to attach two different books to the same genre you just add two rows to the lookup table for example to link book 11,12 to genre 2, just add row1: 11,2, row2:12,2

Comment: If I get it right, in a way I pick up the data I want to be interconnected and I give the command. Thanks, I will try your suggestion